# Property <Object> contains an invalid nested entity. /Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a firestore collection. It gives me the error below in respose.

> "Property images contain an invalid nested entity."

The attempted JSON object is below -->

```
{id: '', name: 'service 1', description: 'service 1 desc', status: 'ACTIVE', images: Array(5), …}
```

Inner images array, image object is below-->

```
{fileId: 0, fileName: 'pexels-helena-lopes-697244.jpg', fileType: 'image/jpeg', fileUrl: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD…83creJTiULjHvxWDwOY1BzDLKFS4NspmW7lTMzBg4lT//2Q==', file: File}
```

Comment: It's probably caused by the `File` object, at the end of the `image` Object. What is the type of the `File` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore can only store types that are listed in its documentation on [data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). If you look carefully, you can see that your data contains a `File` value, which is not in the list of types that Firestore supports.

If you want to store the file's contents in Firebase, the idiomatic approach is to [upload the file to Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) and then store its path (or a [download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url)) in Firestore.

Comment: Thanks... That was the issue. removing File from JSON fix the issue.